# Most elegant way to check if number is in a list of ranges and output a value

Tags: python

What is the best way to code this pythonicly without the use of many if statements?

If I have for example, 3 ranges:
1 to 5 gives 'A' back
6 to 10 gives 'B' back
11 to 15 gives 'C' back

I want to check if a number is within those ranges then give me the associated value.

Considered using dictionary of xranges as keys with values.

```
dic = {xrange(1,5) : 'A',
       xrange(6,10) : 'B',
       xrange(11, 15) : 'C'}

def test(my_num):
    for key, val in dic.items():
        if my_num in key:
            return val

test(8)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is an inefficient way to store that data. You can go back and assemble the `dic` in a different way if possible. As an addition, you can rewrite it using a double comprehension. You don't see those often but it could be appropriate here.

```
lookup = {
    value: label for range, value in dic.items for value in range
}
```